# Jersey : File Uploading Issue

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using jersey 1.9.1. FormDataMultiPart compile error gone when I included jersey-multipart of com.sun.jersey[not org.glassfish]. However, it throws the following error at runtime. Any fix, please!

```
Mar 22, 2017 1:52:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey] in web application [/csmgt] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getMethods(MethodList.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1522)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295)
```

Comment: Have you checked the jar is contained in the deployed WAR ?

Comment: You deployed in tomcat

Comment: which jar are you refering? Do you mean jersey-multipart.jar? It's deployed in Tomcat. I can see it under referenced libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following jersey code for uploading image files ,

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object fileupload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                             @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,@Context HttpContext context){
            String tenant = context.getRequest().getAbsolutePath().getHost(); 
            Session session = null;

            try{
                LOGGER.info("--- File upload request ---");
                session = TenantSesionFactory.openSession(tenant);


                return this.fileUploadProcess.upload(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail,session);

            }catch (BadRequestException e ) {
                throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
             }catch(Exception e){
                LOGGER.error("error in host -> "+tenant,e);
                throw new UncaughtException();
            }finally{
                TenantSessionManager.close(session);
            }


    }
```

I received file as inputstream.

Comment: I don't want to use @FormDataParam because one thing I want to take advantage of FormDataMultiPart another reason is I want to avoid using annotation as an argument.